# Mockito: How to test a class's void method?

Tags: mockito, junit5

Unit test noob here.

I have three classes: `Db1Dao`, `Db2Dao`, `ExecuteClass` where `Db1Dao`, `Db2Dao` are database access objects for two different databases. My goal is to fetch some data from db1 using `Db1Dao` and run `executeClass.execute()` to "put" the processed data into db2 using `Db2Dao`.

My `ExecuteClass` looks like this:

```
class ExecuteClass {

  private Db1Dao db1Dao;
  private Db2Dao db2Dao;

  public void execute() {

    ...
 
    List<String> listOfString = getExternalData(someParam);
    List<Metadata> metadatum = db1Dao.get(someInputs);
    
    ... I do something to generate a list of new class `A` based on listOfString & metadatum ...

    
    try {
        db2Dao.put(listOfA);
    } catch (PutException e){
        ...
    }
    


  }

  public List<String> getExternalData(SomeClass someParam){
    
    ... do something 
    
    return listOfString;
  }

}
```

Now I want to test:

Given a specific `listOfString` (returned by `getExternalData`) and a specific `metadatum` (returned by `db1Dao.get`):

1. Will I get the desired `listOfA`?
2. Am I able to call `db2Dao.put` and its input parameter is `listOfA`?

Particularly, I have hard-coded sample `listOfString` and `metadatum` and desired `listOfA` (and they will be passed via an object `MockData`, see the following code) but I don't know how to write the test using Mockito. The following is a test class I wrote but it does not work:

```
class TestClass extends BaseTest {

    @Mock
    private Db1Dao db1Dao;

    @Mock
    private Db2Dao db2Dao;

    private ExecuteClass executeClass;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        executeClass = new ExecuteClass(db1Dao, db2Dao);
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("MockDataProvider")
    public void executeClassTest(final MockData mockData) throws PutException {

        Mockito.when(db1Dao.get(Mockito.any(), ...))
                .thenReturn(mockData.getMetadatum());

        ExecuteClass executeClassSpy = Mockito.spy(executeClass);
        Mockito.when(executeClassSpy.getExternalData(Mockito.any()))
                .thenReturn(mockData.getListOfString());

        
        executeClassSpy.execute();
        // executeClass.execute(); not working neither...

        List<A> listOfA = mockData.getDesiredListOfA();
        Mockito.verify(db2Dao).put(listOfA);
    }
}
```

Could anyone please let me know? Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You should not create a spy of the same class you want to test. Instead, try to write a unit test for the smallest amount of code (e.g. a public method) and mock every external operator (in your case `Db1Dao` and `Db2Dao`).

If testing a public method involves calling another public method of the same class, make sure to mock everything inside the other public method (in your case `getExternalData`). Otherwise, this other public method might be a good candidate for an extra class to have clear separation of concerns.

So, remove the `ExecuteClass executeClassSpy = Mockito.spy(executeClass);` and make sure you setup everything with Mockito what's called within `getExternalData`.

To now actually, verify that `Db2Dao` was called with the correct parameter, either use your current approach with verifying the payload. But here it's important to 100% create the same data structure you get while executing your application code.

Another solution would be to use Mockito's `@Captor`. This allows you to capture the value of why verifying the invocation of a mock. Later on, you can also write assertions on the captured value:

```
@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<ClassOfListOfA> argumentCaptor;

  
@Test
public void yourTest() {

  Mockito.verify(db2Dao).put(argumentCaptor.capture());
  assertEquals("StringValue", argumentCaptur.getValue().getWhateverGetterYouHave);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! If I remove "spy" and directly use `Mockito.When(executeClass.getExternalData(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(mockData.getListOfString())`, then I got `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: ` Any suggestions?

Comment: you should **not** mock any method of the class you are testing. Try to mock anything that's inside the `getExternal` method

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me.

I partially accepted @rieckpil's answer. I used `@Captor` which is very handy.

The reason I had to mock `getExternalData()` is because its implementation is still a "TODO".

```
class TestClass extends BaseTest {

    @Mock
    private Db1Dao db1Dao;

    @Mock
    private Db2Dao db2Dao;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<List<A>> argumentCaptor;

    private ExecuteClass executeClass;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        executeClass = new ExecuteClass(db1Dao, db2Dao);
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("MockDataProvider")
    public void executeClassTest(final MockData mockData) throws PutException {

        Mockito.when(db1Dao.get(Mockito.any(), ...))
                .thenReturn(mockData.getMetadatum());

        ExecuteClass executeClassSpy = Mockito.spy(executeClass);
        Mockito.when(executeClassSpy.getExternalData(Mockito.any()))
                .thenReturn(mockData.getListOfString());

        executeClassSpy.execute();

        List<A> listOfA = mockData.getDesiredListOfA();

        Mockito.verify(db2Dao).put(argumentCaptor.capture());

        assertEquals(listOfA, argumentCaptor.getValue());
        
    }
}
```